# Field format when saving joined layer from xls

Tags: qgis, shapefile, attribute-joins, excel, fields-attributes

If I perform a join of an xls file to a shapefile and then save it as another shapefile, my numeric fields from the xls are displayed with many decimal ceroes.

Here is an example: The upper table is the result of saving the joined table (which is below).

[image]

When I check the type of field in the properties window of the original (joined) shape, it is a double - real- 0 length - 0 precision.
In the new saved shapefile the type of field is double - real- 23 length - 15 precision.

How can I get the numbers with no decimals automatically?

Comment: what were the format of those columns when they lived in Excel?

Comment: They were numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could reproduce this behavior using Excel2013.

Observations:

- If a table is saved as an **.xlsx** (current Excel format), input integer value (31661) is kept as integer when drag & dropped into QGIS.
- If a table is saved as an **.xls** (older Excel 97-2013 format), input integer value (31661) becomes a double (31661.000...) when drag & dropped into QGIS. (Confirmed Pescariz's OP).
- If a table is saved as an **.csv** and read by `Add vector layer`  they become text fields (31661).
- Join operation keeps the inherited field type. Saving the layer as a new Shapefile also does not affect the type.

Workaround:

(Option 1) Save it as latest Excel format (.xlsx) before reading it to QGIS.

(Option 2) Read the .xls file same as before, then use the QGIS `Refactor tool` to change the type to `Integer` before Join.

(Option 3) Save .xls as a .csv and use `Add Delimited Text Layer`... it will try to read number field as number (unlike the `Add vector layer`).

Comment: I usually work with .xls file because is the format allowed for the tool "Open Excel as point table", very useful for me.